# Error:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In If statement in R

Tags: r, lapply

I want to run a coxph function on each column in my dataframe and return matrix with the column's name, coefficient and p_value.

My code so far:

```
names <- colnames(df)[c(1:length(df))]
df <- na.omit(df)

res <-  lapply(names, function(i)   {
iformula <- as.formula(sprintf("surv_object ~ %s ", i))  
x <- coxph(iformula, data=df, na.action=na.omit)
if (coef(summary(x))[5] < 0.05)  {
(summary(x)[7][[1]]) })

matrix <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
Error in if (coef(summary(x))[5] < 0.05) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Most likely `coef(summary(x))[5]` evaluates to `NA`. You may reproduce a similar error with `if (NA < 0.05) print("Hello")`

Comment: You could replace `if (coef(summary(x))[5] < 0.05)` by `if(isTRUE( (coef(summary(x))[5] < 0.05))`

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example to verify possible solutions? Apart from the `NA` issue I think you should also have an `else` part there.

Comment: @Waldi- Thanks- that's solved my problem.